# how to resolve probability exercice 1.13 Grimmett

Tags: probability

A square board is divided into 16 equal squares by lines drawn parallel to its sides. A counter is placed at random on one of these squares and is then moved n times. At each of these moves, it can be transferred to any neighbouring square, horizontally, vertically, or diagonally, all such moves being equally likely.

Let $c_{n}$ be the probability that a particular corner site is occupied after n such independent moves, and let the corresponding probabilities for an intermediate site at the side of the board and for a site in the middle of the board be $s_{n}$ and $m_{n}$, respectively. Show that $$4c_{n}+8s_{n}+4m_{n} = 1, n =0,1,2,...$$
and that
$$ c_{n}=\frac{2}{5}s_{n-1}+\frac{1}{8}m_{n-1}, n = 1,2,...$$
Find two other relations for $s_{n}$ and $m_{n}$ in terms of $c_{n-1}, s_{n-1},$ and $m_{n-1}$ -> ok, I found it

And hence find $c_{n},s_{n},$ and $m_{n}$. -> how to do it by iteration ? and in what form should be the final answer ?

edit : I don't ask you to resolve it for me, i would like to receive a hint, I am not used to the linear recurrence relation.
I am lost and I don't know what to do. I substituted the $m_{n-1}$ and $s_{n-1}$ in $c_{n}$, do I need to make an induction proof ? Do I need to use a special method ?

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1):

The first statement, $$4c_n + 8s_n + 4m_n = 1$$ is simply the statement that the counter must be on the board after $n$ moves.  This should be obvious if you draw out the $4\times4$ board and label the squares with $c,m$ and $s$.  At this step it's also worth noting that since the counter is placed on the board at random (i.e. all squares can be chosen equally) we have $$c_0 = s_0 = m_0 = 1/16$$

For the second statement, we look at how at counter can, on the $n^{\mbox {th}}$ turn move to a corner square.  There are three squares adjacent to a corner, two side squares and one middle-square.  So if the counter was on a side square on at the end of move $n-1$ it has $5$ squares it can move to on move $n$, one of which is our corner square.  Similarly, if it's on the middle square there is a $1/8$ chance of the counter moving to our corner square.  So, $$c_n = \frac{2}{5}s_{n-1} + \frac{1}{8}m_{n-1}$$
where the factor of $2$ comes from there being two side squares that can reach the corner.

You say you've found the formulae for $s_n$ and $m_n$ so I won't take this further, but they're done using the same considerations: where can the counter be at the end of move $n-1$? and what's the probability of it moving onto a side (or middle) square?

So, to complete finding $c_n, s_n$ and $m_n$ you need to use the initial state: $c_0, s_0$ and $m_0$ and your formulae.  We know that $$c_n = \frac{2}{5}s_{n-1} + \frac{1}{8}m_{n-1}$$ so we have that $$c_1 = \frac{2}{5}\cdot \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{8}\cdot \frac{1}{16} = \frac{21}{640}$$  For $c_2$ you have to substitute in your formulae for $s_1$ and $m_1$ and then solve for $c_2$.  This can then be generalised to allow you to solve for $c_n$, $s_n$ and $m_n$.

Comment: Thank you postmortes. Isn't $c_{1}=\frac{2}{5}\frac{8}{16}+\frac{1}{8}\frac{4}{8}$ ?

Comment: It can't be: $4c_0 +8s_0 +4m_0 =1$ by the first statement, so $c_0=s_0=m_0=1/16$.

Comment: ok, so is it correct that $m_n=3m_{n-1}\frac{3}{8}+c_{n-1}\frac{1}{3}+4s_{n-1}\frac{2}{5}, s_n=2s_{n-1}\frac{2}{5}+c_{n-1}\frac{2}{3}+2m_{n-1}\frac{4}{8}$ ?
so $s_1=\frac{37}{240}$ and $m_1=\frac{367}{1920}$ and so $c_2=\frac{6571}{76800}$ ?

Comment: No, it can't be.  If you calculate $8s_1$ with your value you get $1.233333\ldots$.  But $4c_1 + 8s_1 + 4m_1 =1 $ still

Comment: @Did thanks for the edit :)

Comment: We have $m_n=\frac{3}{8}m_{n−1}+\frac{1}{3}c_{n−1}+\frac{4}{5}s_{n−1}, s_n=\frac{1}{3}s_{n−1}+\frac{2}{8}m_{n-1}+\frac{2}{5}s_{n-1}$
So $c_1=\frac{63}{1920}, m_1= \frac{181}{1920}, s_1= \frac{118}{1920}$ and so $c_2=\frac{1913}{76800}$, but I don't see how to generalized.